# Polynomial with root $α = \sqrt{2}+\sqrt{5}$ and using it to simplify $α^6$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, roots

Find a polynomial $\space P(X) \in \mathbb{Q}[X]\space$ of degree 4 such that

$$\alpha = \sqrt{2} + \sqrt{5}$$

Is a root of $P$.

Using this polynomial, find numbers $\space a, b, c, d \space$ such that

$$\alpha^{6} = a + b\alpha + c\alpha^{2} + d\alpha^{3}$$

*What have I tried so far?*

I know obviously that for $\alpha$ to be a root of $P$, then $(x-\alpha)$ must be part of the polynomial. Hence, $(x-\sqrt{2} - \sqrt{5})$ will be a factor of the polynomial. Where I’m getting stuck is what to do next in order to find the other factors of the polynomial such that I get values $a, b, c$ and $d$ that satisfy the equation with $\alpha^{6}$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: +1 for a well written question, showing your work.

Comment: It looks like $\alpha ^6=a+\alpha  b+\alpha ^2 c+\alpha ^3 d$ has infinite solutions for $a,b,c,d$. Indeed $$\left(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{5}\right)^6=a+\left(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{5}\right) b+\left(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{5}\right)^2 c+\left(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{5}\right)^3 d$$ is indeterminate. Or there is something I'm missing here

Comment: @Raffaele I'm guessing that the context of this question is a Galois theory/algebraic number theory class, in which case the intention would be for $a,b,c,d$ to be rational numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use the following identity.
$$(a+b+c)\prod_{cyc}(a+b-c)=\sum_{cyc}(2a^2b^2-a^4).$$
We obtain:
$$2\alpha^2\cdot2+2\alpha^2\cdot5+2\cdot2\cdot5-\alpha^4-2^2-5^2=0$$ or
$$\alpha^4-14\alpha^2+9=0.$$
From here $$\alpha^6=14\alpha^4-9\alpha^2=14(14\alpha^2-9)-9\alpha^2=187\alpha^2-126,$$ which gives $$(a,b,c,d)=(-126,0,187,0).$$

Comment: would I then multiply everything by $\alpha^2$?

Comment: @butter chi   Yes, for the solution of your second problem. I added something. See now.

Comment: thank you so much for your help, I managed to solve it to get the same answer as you!

Comment: @butter chi You are welcome!

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

$a^2=(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{5})^2=2+5+2\sqrt{10}=7+2\sqrt{10}\Rightarrow a^2-7=2\sqrt{10} \Rightarrow (a^2-7)^2=40$

Edit

$(a^2-7)^2=40 \Rightarrow a^4-14a^2+49=40 \Rightarrow a^4-14a^2+9=0$

Comment: I can understand what you have done here but I'm not quite sure what this solves? Does this mean $c=40$?

Comment: @butter chi  I have edited my answer

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer the question. I now understand it's just a matter of manipulating $\alpha$

Comment: Yes, I'll agree!

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking at this from the wrong perspective. Some basic Galois Theory will tell you what the other roots of the polynomial are (hint: consider how it's constructed. Whenever we conduct a squaring operation, we 'spawn' another solution corresponding to the negative of whatever quantity is being squared). But those other roots aren't actually relevant to solving the question of how to write $\alpha^6$.

Instead, consider doing some 'modular' algebra: you know that $\alpha^4=14\alpha^2-9$ (as other answers have showed). You can use this to 'reduce' any term of size $\alpha^4$ or larger in a polynomial expression to a term that's of smaller degree. For instance, by multiplying by $\alpha$ we see that $\alpha^5=14\alpha^3-9\alpha$. Now, multiply both sides of this by $\alpha$; can you see a spot to use the relation again?

Comment: Great! Thank you for taking the time to reply. I now understand to keep computing until $\alpha^6$ and use the $\alpha^4$ equation

Answer (score 0):

We have
$$\left( x-\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2}\right) \, \left( x-\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2}\right) \, \left( x+\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2}\right) \, \left( x+\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2}\right) ={{x}^{4}}-10 {{x}^{2}}+1 \tag{1}$$
and further
$$ x^6=({{x}^{2}}+10)({{x}^{4}}-10 {{x}^{2}}+1)+(99 {{x}^{2}}-10)$$
So
$$\alpha^6=99 \alpha^2-10$$
Instead of guessing $(1)$ you can find a polynomial of degree 4 by using the method described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1254901/11206) by @HagenvonEitzen.